# using vbs, how can I determine the name of the RDP client running on my desktop?

Tags: vbscript, rdp

I'd like to use "sendkeys" to an rdp session, but I think I'd first need to put the focus on the RDP window on my desktop. How can I determine that dynamically?
If I use AppActivate, how can I determine the name of the RDP session?

Comment: *I'd like to use "sendkeys"* - No, you don't. Not unless someone's forcing you at gunpoint. Trust me on that one. You're probably looking for [`AppActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), but again, you really don't want to use `SendKeys`. It's a very, *very* poor way of automating stuff, and should only be used as a last resort (if at all).

Answer (score 0):

AppActivate is the only window manipulation function available to script. As a general rule programs don't mess with other programs' windows.

However `tasklist /v` lists the main window title for a program.

This code gets it from CMD.

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Set cmd = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("cmd")
cmd.stdin.writeline "tasklist /fi ""imagename eq mstsc.exe"" /v"
wscript.sleep 2000
cmd.stdin.writeline "exit"
Do While Not cmd.stdout.AtEndOfStream 
    results = cmd.stdout.readall
    If err.number <> 0 then Exit Do
        wscript.echo results
Loop
```

Also see my article here on how to access API from VBS using VB.NET.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df0248cb-612f-4e2f-9665-11c68c401458/this-is-how-to-call-win32-api-calls-in-vbscript-and-jscript-sample-windows-api-functions?forum=scripting

and [How to find the window Title of Active(foreground) window using Window Script Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341753/how-to-find-the-window-title-of-activeforeground-window-using-window-script-ho/26349431#26349431)