# Set priority of active window using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

i use this code to set the priority of a running program:

```
set /p input=Program name:
wmic process where name="%input%" CALL setpriority "high priority"
```

Is there a way i can run the batch file then open my program and let the batch set priority without typing the name? mabye something that looks like this:

```
timeout 3 /nobreak >nul
wmic process active window CALL setpriority "high priority"
```

Comment: See `start /?` you can start a program AND set its' Priority. `start "" /wait /high c:\folder\myprogram.exe`

Comment: PS Any active window automatically gets a priority boost. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684828(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Noodles I will use this on already open programs so the start command cant do it. I know that active programs gets a priority boost, but i want my programs to run at high even i a diffrent program is active.

Comment: That not quite what your question says. *Is there a way i can run the batch file then open my program and let the batch set priority*.

Comment: You cannot easily get active windows in scripting languages (programs shouldn't mess with other programs). You can make a .NET executable (see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341753/how-to-find-the-window-title-of-activeforeground-window-using-window-script-ho/26369890#26369890).